# Easy way to resolve available messages from a set of codes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm working on a Spring MVC project (Spring Boot v1.4.2) and I need to resolve some error codes from the localized `message.properties` file.

For example, one of the validation errors I get is this:

```
org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'signUpDTO' on field 'email': rejected value [email@hotmail.com]; codes [EmailAlreadyUsed.signup.signUpDTO.email,EmailAlreadyUsed.signup.email,EmailAlreadyUsed.signup.java.lang.String,EmailAlreadyUsed.signup]; arguments []; default message [null]
```

As you can see a list of error codes is generated starting from the basic error code (`EmailAlreadyUsed.signup`) :

```
codes [EmailAlreadyUsed.signup.signUpDTO.email,EmailAlreadyUsed.signup.email,EmailAlreadyUsed.signup.java.lang.String,EmailAlreadyUsed.signup];
```

I'd like to check if any of these codes are defined in my `message.properties` and resolve the message associated to it.

At the moment I'm using this utility class that resolve a single code:

```
@Component
public class LocalizedMessageProvider {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    public String getMessage(String code , Object... arguments) {
        Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
        return messageSource.getMessage(code, arguments, locale);
    }
}
```

Is there some out-of-the-box utility in Spring or should I simply iterate through every error code?

Comment: You can try using Spring Expression Language (SpEL). There were some similar requirements for one of the projects I was working on and I end up using `@Value` in conjunction with SpEL to achieve it.

Comment: @user2004685 please, can you explain your approach as an answer? thanks

Comment: It seems like you have already found a way to do it. Let me know if you still need any help with it.

Comment: @user2004685 yes I'd like to know your approach to the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just discovered that `MessageSource` interface declares this method:

[`getMessage(MessageSourceResolvable resolvable, Locale locale)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html#getMessage-org.springframework.context.MessageSourceResolvable-java.util.Locale-)

that accepts a `MessageSourceResolvable` object (therefore any validation error built internally by Spring) and works in a way similar to what I need.

It takes every error code generated for the validation error and check if at least one associated message is declared in the message resource bundle.

Comment: You can also use MessageSourceAccessor to skip the "Locale" part.